# How to access the next string with the ++ operator in a character array of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

```
    // This is an array which contains char pointers.
    // These char pointers will be pointing to strings.
    char* strings_array[100];

    strings_array[0] = (char*)"anisha";
    strings_array[1] = (char*)"kaul";
    strings_array[2] = (char*)"shizuka";
    strings_array[3] = (char*)"sharma";

    // Access the whole 1st string.
    std::cout << *strings_array;

    // Access the whole 2nd string.
    std::cout << strings_array[1];
```

Above is what I tried and it worked. ***I want to know how to get to the 2nd string by using ++ operator.***

Putting ++ as pre or post fix with `strings_array` results in the `lvalue required error`.

Comment: Is what you are saying that you want to acces them like: `std::cout<< *strings_array; std::cout<<*(strings_array++);`? I do not know if that works, just asking to clarifiy what you want.

Comment: How do you expect it to work? `int i = 0; ++i; std::cout << strings_array[i];`?

Comment: (why are there so many deleted answers here?)

Comment: @apalomer _" I do not know if that works"_ No, that doesn't work you can't increment an array type.

Comment: Looks like an useful FAQ question for beginners.

Comment: You do realise that all of this is unnecessary because `std::vector<std::string>` turns the pointer party into a boring one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strings_array` as declared in:

```
char* strings_array[100];
```

is a *non-modifiable* lvalue, so it can't become the operand of the `++` operator, because it does modify its operand.

However, you can define `ptr` as a pointer to the first element of the array `strings_array`:

```
char **ptr = &strings_array[0];
```

This `ptr` is a *modifiable lvalue*, so it can become the operand of `++`.

Comment: Well,  I don't want to modify anything, I just want to move the pointer to next string. Is it just not possible with ++?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl `++` must modify the pointer, so that it points to the next element.

Answer (score 1):

when we are storing more than one characters in a char array datatype automatically it is double dimension.char* is pointer to char datatype.char** is pointer to pointer char.Here we have already declared char* strings_array so have to use char** to store  the address of char pointer variable.using that we can access the string elements one by one by increment the address by using ++ operator in char** variable.

in our example cpr is char** variable initially the starting address of char* strings_array is stored and cpr++ increments the address because cpr is char** which stores the address of char*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
 {
   char* strings_array[100];
   strings_array[0] = (char*)"anisha";
   strings_array[1] = (char*)"kaul";
   strings_array[2] = (char*)"shizuka";
   strings_array[3] = (char*)"sharma";
   cout <<"\n"<< *strings_array;
   cout <<"\n"<< strings_array[1];
   char **cpr=&strings_array[0];
   cout<<"\n String Values using string pointer";
   cout<<"\n------------------------------------";
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
     {
       cout<<"\n"<<*(cpr);
       cpr++;
      }
   return 0;

}
```

OUTPUT

```
anisha                                                                                                                                         
kaul  

String Values using string pointer                                                                                                            
------------------------------------                                                                                                           
anisha                                                                                                                                         
kaul                                                                                                                                           
shizuka                                                                                                                                        
sharma
```

hope that u understand the concept.Thank you